# Joomla comet chat not inserting messages to db tables

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, cometchat

I installed cometchat from cometchat.com on joomla. Chat bar shows on UI but when I type it wont insert the message to cometchat table in mysql db. What may be the issue?

Comment: can you please create a ticket and provide us with the necessary server details ​as that would be helpful for us?

Comment: Please make sure you have downloaded CometChat with Joomla Integration and refer the following link for the installation:
https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/installing-cometchat/ready-integrations/joomla/ If you still face any issues with CometChat, feel free to create a support ticket and CometChat developers will assist you in fixing them. Regards,
CometChat